# How to produce errors\exceptions in callback functions in mongoose for testing purpose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with MongoDB using Mongoose. Most of the opeartion works with callback. An error may occur while saving/updating/finding a document. Though we can always check if there an error in callback function (as shown in below code) but I want to know while developing how can we generate error and test these blocks?

```
Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  tank.size = 'large';
  tank.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(tank);
  });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the `Error` class?  Emiting errors with the `EventEmitter`? Throwing errors with `throw`?

[This link](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) is a fairly extensive overview on how to deal with errors in node.

Assuming your using express, in the case of the example you provided, I would usually create an instance of the `Error` class doing something like:

```
exports.findTankById = function(req, res, next) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
        if (err) {
            var e = new Error("Failed to find tank");
            e.data = err;
            // attach other useful data to error class instance
            return next(e);
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ data: tank });
    })
});
```

Then in another part of the application, have a middleware function that catches errors passed by your routes via `next()`.  That function could log the error or doing something more creative.  Note that when using `new Error(...)` you can access the stack using the stack attribute of the `Error` class (e.g. `err.stack`). After processing the error, the error handler function would send back an appropriate response.

A simple error handler function could look something like:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if(err.data) {
        // caught operational errors
        /* do something to log or process error */
        var response = {
            type : 'error',
            description : err.message  // this would use "Failed to get tank" for above example
        };
        res.status(500).json(response);
    } else {
        // unexpected errors
        var domainThrown = err.domain_thrown || err.domainThrown;
        var msg = 'domainThrown: ' + domainThrown + '\n' + err.stack;
        console.error('%s %s\n%s', req.method, req.url, msg);
        res.set('Connection', 'close');
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(503).send(msg + '\n');
    }
});
```

If you like this approach, I usually define more specific error objects of my own that more or less extend the `Error` class.  Using functions to create the more specific error types limits the need to write out the

```
var e = new Error("Failed to find tank");
e.data = err;
/* attach other useful data to error class instance */
```

part every time.  Using more specific error objects also forces consistency on how the errors are being formatted.  Hope that is helpful,

Craig

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know how to produce the errors in order to test the error block. I dont want to know how to handle the errors. Your answer is more towards handling the errors.

Comment: I see, AFAIK you will have to trigger the errors you want to test on a case by case basis.  Break a constraint on a save, kill a database connection on a find, etc.